# Unity tweak tool broke unity

Tags: unity

I was poking through the settings in unity tweak tool, adjusted a few things just to see what they did. Like window behavior on sides/corners multi desktops (forgot what they are called in ubuntu)

The very last thing I touched was the reset button and it broke it. My top bar is now gone, the launcher is gone, and the super key wont start a search. I have tried a ton of things I've read to fix it without luck, will list what I have tried.

tried reseting unity "unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity" it asks me to log out and back in which I am not sure how to do via terminal as I have no top bar to do the normal way. I logged out by using sudo service lightdm reset but I dont know if that is correct, it got me back to the login screen but upon log in everythings the same.

I tried running unity via terminal and get:
unity-panel-service stop/waiting
unity7 stop/waiting
unity-panel-service start/running, process 3102 unity7 start/running, process 3104

those numbers change sometimes but it never works, screen flashes a bit, some windows come and go but then in the end nothing stays.

I went to restore from back in time but through terminal it says its not configured which i dont understand because I had it doing daily backups with back in time root. Which I watched it do the first one but now cannot find.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a startup usb?

Comment: Ideally what you'd need to have is `CompizConfig Settings Manager` . Unity in and of itself is just a plugin to compiz. Sometimes ( for whatever reason ) those plugins get unset (reset button could have done that) , and one looses launcher and panel , which are really just plugins to compiz.  I've broken my Unity multiple times, and each time all that was needed to do is to reenable Unity plugin and a few others , like Desktop Wall and Viewport Switcher

Comment: Thank you, that worked. It hung on enabling unity and when I eventually gave up and closed everything unity came back up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you can access the internet.
This solved it when it happened to me.

Type the following on a terminal. (Right click on the desktop to open one)

```
sudo apt-get install dconf
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
setsid unity
unity --reset-icons
```

Comment: Gave that a shot, it does flashes all the windows on screen a few times and nothing.says the following:unity-panel-service stop/waiting unity7 stop/waiting unity-panel-service start/running, process 3113 unity7 start/running, process 3265